# Custom WritableComparable Issue - reducer never gets called

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

Driver Class

```
public class abdDriver {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {
            Path input = new Path("amazon.txt");
            Path output = new Path("./outPutData");

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
            job.setJarByClass(abdDriver.class);

            job.setMapperClass(abdMapper.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);


            job.setReducerClass(abdReducer.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


            job.setInputFormatClass(abdRecordReader.class);
            //job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);

            output.getFileSystem(job.getConfiguration()).delete(output, true);

            job.waitForCompletion(true);

            System.out.println("Completed successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Mapper Class

```
public class abdMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, abdRecordClass, LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, abdRecordClass value, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (value.getTITLE().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            con.write(key, value.getTITLE());
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + value.getTITLE() + "\t" + value.getCATEGORIES());
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer Class

```
public class abdReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> value, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("reducer");

        for (Text t : value) {
            System.out.println(t);
            con.write(NullWritable.get(), t);
        }
    }

}
```

custom writablecomparable class

```
public class abdRecordClass implements WritableComparable<abdRecordClass> {

    private Text ID, ASIN, TITLE, GROUP, SALESRANK, REV_SUMMARY,

    SIMILAR, CATEGORIES, REVIEWS;

    public abdRecordClass() {
        ID = new Text();
        ASIN = new Text();
        TITLE = new Text();
        GROUP = new Text();
        SALESRANK = new Text();
        REV_SUMMARY = new Text();
        SIMILAR = new Text();
        CATEGORIES = new Text();
        REVIEWS = new Text();
        ;
    }

    public abdRecordClass(Text id, Text asin, Text title, Text group, Text rank, Text similar, Text cat, Text rev_summary, Text reviews) {
        super();
        this.ID = id;
        this.ASIN = asin;
        this.TITLE = title;
        this.GROUP = group;
        this.SALESRANK = rank;
        this.SIMILAR = similar;
        this.CATEGORIES = cat;
        this.REV_SUMMARY = rev_summary;
        this.REVIEWS = reviews;
        System.out.println("new record created");
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("read fields");
        this.ID.readFields(in);
        this.ASIN.readFields(in);
        this.TITLE.readFields(in);
        this.GROUP.readFields(in);
        this.SALESRANK.readFields(in);
        this.SIMILAR.readFields(in);
        this.CATEGORIES.readFields(in);
        this.REV_SUMMARY.readFields(in);
        this.REVIEWS.readFields(in);

    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {

        this.ID.write(out);
        System.out.println("write fields");
        this.ASIN.write(out);
        this.TITLE.write(out);
        this.GROUP.write(out);
        this.SALESRANK.write(out);
        this.SIMILAR.write(out);
        this.CATEGORIES.write(out);
        this.REV_SUMMARY.write(out);
        this.REVIEWS.write(out);

    }
}
```

Problems is:
code is working fine upto mapper, as sysout in mapper gives perfect output,but after mapper reducer us never gets called.
is there anything wrong with writablecomparable class?

Comment: is there some exception after map finishes ?

Comment: no there is no error or exceptions. just exit from the program. no output

Comment: can you show us what gets printed when you execute the job ? paste it to this site : http://pastebin.com/ , also the version of hadoop and OS would be good

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/nRq10u8d , i m using cloudera 5.5

Comment: Here is the whole project link with dataset. just import project into eclipe. please let me know where m i doing wrong :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hSFb0kVpsJTjh1VXg3MEEzWDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you understood me wrong, I want what gets printed after you issue `hadoop jar ...`, those `[INFO] ...` and alike :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vjb8q4yG here is the output , this is sysout from mapper class. problem is i m passing class as value from recordreader to mapper , this class is implemented by writablecomparable too.

Comment: it's not what you sysout that I want, it's what hadoop sysouts, something like the number of map tasks,reduce tasks, I expected to see [INFO] started job,... maybe [WARN] maybe [ERROR], I don't see them in your pastebin :)

Comment: hmmm I think the problem is in `Path output=new Path("./outPutData")`, I think you should put the absolute path, also `output.getFileSystem(job.getConfiguration()).delete(output, true);` will make the output files disappear (part-r-XXXXX and SUCCESS)

Comment: can i have ur emai address i can send u code directly and for better conversation

Comment: you already have code in google drive link , anyway I tried importing into Intellij(I prefer it over eclipse) but there were many libraries missing, I know hadoop has libs but there were others not hadoop related